# Chakra UI _blur styles from theme

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I'm applying custom theme to an Input component in ChakraUI.
Here I'm using **_focus** pseudo class in the **baseStyle --> field** section.

My question is do we have something like **_blur** ?
What should I do to handle focusOut ?

```
const baseStyle = definePartsStyle({
  field: {
    _placeholder: {
      opacity: 0.5,
    },
    _focus: {
      borderColor: #fff',
    },
  },
})
```

tried searching the chakra docs but didn't get anything specific to handle focusOutfrom the Theme itself